# Testing SSH connection to git prompts password

Tags: git, ssh

we have set up a local Git server and enabled the SSH settings on it. Following the guide [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/#testing-that-everything-is-set-up-correctly) we tested the SSH key but it still prompt us for password. Below is the log from the ssh:

```
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /c/Users/Eugene/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:XXX
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/Eugene/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /c/Users/Eugene/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/Eugene/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /c/Users/Eugene/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/Eugene/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /c/Users/Eugene/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/Eugene/.ssh/id_xmss
debug3: no such identity: /c/Users/Eugene/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
git@git.test.com's password:
```

The guide says something wrong with the SSH setup. I am not able to see where, hope to get some help here.

Answer (score 0):

What's the output from `ssh -T git@github.com`?

From the debug output, the ssh client cannot locate where your private keys are stored.  I'd troubleshoot by checking the following:

- Make sure you've added keys with ssh-agent.
- Double check and see if your configuration file ( `~/.ssh/config`) has the correct path pointing to your identity file.

Comment: The output from ssh -T git@github.com is the above log. For ~/.ssh/config, the contents:
Host git
 Hostname git.test.com
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa